# how to include @mdi/font in laravel(7.2)

Tags: laravel, npm

i am trying to include this(https://materialdesignicons.com/) package in my fresh laravel(7.2) project
i have done this so far
`npm install @mdi/font` 
and i can see the package in the
[image]

but when i add this line in my welcome.blade.php

```
 Bob lives in a <span class="mdi mdi-home"></span>.
```

the output i get is:
[image]

i have also build and run my npm but i still get nothing. futher more i have also tried importing it in my `app.js` file right on top like this
`import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My laravel is 6.x:

```
# npm install -D @mdi/font node-sass
```

Open resources/sass/app.scss

```
// Fonts
@import "~@mdi/font/scss/materialdesignicons.scss";
```

Than:

```
# npm run dev
```

If no errors display[enter image description here][1], you'll see mdi fonts in your public folder...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6SHC.png